# "Adb Transfer Protocol Error. Permission denied." Run APK for i9300 on Mac

Tags: android, apk, android-studio, android-install-apk

As title told, I tried several times. 
It's confirmed that USB Debug is on in i9300 settings. 
The apk is ok with emulator.
I can't figure out why this behaves and how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it's a problem of driver. The drivers are so difficult to find on Mac, so I have moved my work to Windows 8. Yes, the problem has been solved.